# Sizing a dynamically sized Widget by a factor

Tags: user-interface, layout, dart, flutter

I'm trying to set the `heightFactor` of a dynamically sized `Widget` (for animation purposes), in this case a `Text`:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        FractionallySizedBox(
          heightFactor: 0.5,
          child: Text(
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Lorem ipsum".toUpperCase(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

that however results in the following exception:

```
I/flutter ( 7123): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 7123): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 7123): BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
I/flutter ( 7123): These invalid constraints were provided to RenderParagraph's layout() function by the following
I/flutter ( 7123): function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
I/flutter ( 7123):   RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox.performLayout
I/flutter ( 7123):   (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:909:13)
I/flutter ( 7123): The offending constraints were:
I/flutter ( 7123):   BoxConstraints(w=272.0, h=Infinity)
```

And wrapping the `Text` in either `LimitedBox` or `ConstrainedBox` seems to only change what the invalid constraints were provided to in the error message.

Nor does adding `MainAxisSize.min` to `Column.mainAxisSize` seem to make a difference.

Is there a way to accomplish this that avoids the error?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more of your code than that - for now all I can say is that whatever your FractionallySizedBox is sizing itself to must have an infinite height. Since `infinity / 2 == infinity` your text also has an infinite height. You'll probably have better luck with an Align widget, but it's hard to tell without knowing what your widget is in.

Comment: Okay, updated with more code, sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could describe what it is you're trying to achieve by doing that.

Comment: Okay, `Align` seems to do the trick, so I'll rephrase the question and add an answer.
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Well I can add that as an answer then haha. Glad that helped =).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A FractionallySizedBox sizes itself to its parent. Because you're using a column within a stack it doesn't really have a limit on infinite height. Since `infinity / 2 == infinity` your text therefore also has an infinite height.

If you switch to using an align, you can size your object to the text rather than the parent.